# Optimal control problem using Gekko: “Solution Not Found”

Tags: python, gekko

I need to solve an optimal control problem with an objective function minimization solution. The reference for me is the APM example available at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y26X-BSf8KU&list=PLLBUgWXdTBDjxcpH9hRuq-bsm_ti2UvoB&index=12.

My objective function is Z => integration exp(-r*t)*C(t).dt, where C(t) = Ii.ai + Ij.aj. Ii and Ij are the manipulated variables and ai, aj and r are constants. The goal is min Z.

The problem is subject to the following constraints: dKi/dt = Ii – deltai.Ki; dKj/dt = Ij – deltaj.Kj; and Ki = (D-B.Kj-E)/A. Ki and Kj are variables and the initial values Ki0 and Kj0 are known. D, A, B, deltai, deltaj and E are constants coefficients.

I have developed a Gekko / python script as follow. However, the optimization script not achieves a solution (“Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found”. I have tried to change the initial conditions and the initial guess but I haven´t achieve the solution.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

#Create Gekko model
m=GEKKO()

#Time points
nt=101
m.time=np.linspace(0,10,nt)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

#Constants
A=-0.0000159 
B=-0.0000506 
E=0.614 
deltai=0.031 
deltaj=0.1 
ai=10 
aj=27632 
r=0.085 

Ii=m.MV(value=100)
Ij=m.MV(value=100)
Ii.STATUS=1
Ii.COST=0
Ij.STATUS=1
Ij.COST=0

Ki=m.Var(value=15.548)
Kj=m.Var(value=0.932)

m.Equation(Ki.dt()==Ii-deltai*Ki)
m.Equation(Kj.dt()==Ij-deltaj*Kj)
m.Equation(Ki==(0.577-B*Kj-E)/A)

#Objective
Z=m.Var()

#Final objective
Zf=m.FV()
Zf.STATUS=1
m.Connection(Zf, Z, pos2='end')
m.Equation(Z.dt() == ((m.exp(-r*t)))*(Ii*ai+Ij*aj))

m.Obj(Zf)

#Options
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solver suggests that your problem is unbounded.

```
EXIT: Iterates diverging; problem might be unbounded.
 
 An error occured.
 The error code is            4
 
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    1.44470000000729      sec
 Objective      :  -4.152133137209157E+021
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Desktop\test.py", line 53, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2174, in solve
    raise Exception(response)
Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found
```

Should the `MV`s have bounds?

```py
Ii=m.MV(value=100,lb=0,ub=100)
Ij=m.MV(value=100,lb=0,ub=100)
```

Also, with these bounds the APOPT solver reports that the problem is infeasible. It appears that there are 3 equations for the solution of 2 variables: `Ki` and `Kj`.

```py
m.Equation(Ki.dt()==Ii-deltai*Ki)
m.Equation(Kj.dt()==Ij-deltaj*Kj)
m.Equation(Ki*A==(0.577-B*Kj-E))
```

If you remove the last equation then you get a successful solution. In short, the problem may be unbounded, over-specified, or both. Here is a version that solves successfully:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

m=GEKKO() #Create Gekko model

nt=101 #Time points
m.time=np.linspace(0,10,nt)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)
final = np.zeros(nt); final[-1] = 1
f = m.Param(final)

#Constants
A=-0.0000159; B=-0.0000506; E=0.614 
deltai=0.031; deltaj=0.1 
ai=10; aj=27632; r=0.085 

Ii=m.MV(value=100,lb=0,ub=100)
Ij=m.MV(value=100,lb=0,ub=100)
Ii.STATUS=1; Ii.COST=0
Ij.STATUS=1; Ij.COST=0

Ki=m.Var(value=15.548)
Kj=m.Var(value=0.932)

e = m.Intermediate(m.exp(-r*t))
m.Equation(Ki.dt()==Ii-deltai*Ki)
m.Equation(Kj.dt()==Ij-deltaj*Kj)
#m.Equation(Ki*A==(0.577-B*Kj-E))

#Minimize objective at final point
m.Minimize(f*m.integral(e*(Ii*ai+Ij*aj)))

#Options
m.options.IMODE=6; m.options.NODES=2
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
```

I also used the new `m.integral()` function. You may need to verify your equations and you can also try different solvers to see if one gives you more meaningful information.

```
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :            7
   Intermediates:            1
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            5
   Residuals    :            4
 
 Number of state variables:           1600
 Number of total equations: -         1400
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :            200
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  2.55775E+01  2.61383E+00
    1  1.99997E-03  9.61349E-09
    2  2.00000E-03  1.82031E-10
    3  2.00000E-03  2.22045E-16
    4  2.00000E-03  2.22045E-16
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   0.498800000001211      sec
 Objective      :   1.999999949475750E-003
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you John. I will verify and adjust the script and formulation as you have noted. Kind regards